# Change a line "get_edit_post_link"

Tags: php, wordpress

I know almost nothing about PHP and I need help. I have a WordPress plugin, and I want to change this code:

```
{
    $post = get_post($item['post_id']);

    if (is_a($post, 'WP_Post'))
        return '<a href="' . get_edit_post_link($post->ID) . '#wprc-reports">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';

    return 'Post Not Found';
}
```

the problem is...I don't want to edit that post. I just want to be redirected to the post article.

You can see what I want [image: enter image description here]].

Thank you!

Comment: Which plugin are you using? It can be helpful to view the plugin docs to see if it has, for instance a `get_post_link()` function.

Comment: This is the plugin: https://wordpress.org/plugins/report-content/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The plugin uses the following function in `report-content.php` at line 242 to obtain a post's URL:

`get_post_permalink()`

You can change the code to use this function as follows:

```
if (is_a($post, 'WP_Post'))
  return '<a href="' . get_post_permalink($post->ID) . '#wprc-reports">' . $post->post_title . '</a>';
```

[This](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_post_permalink/) link has more information about the `get_post_permalink()` function.

Please note that **I do not have this plugin installed**, so I have not yet been able to **test** this change.

Comment: I have one more question. Can be added a function or something in Report Content plugin, to show me IP address from any user who report any content in my website? Is good for spammers and i need something like this. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3003145/how-to-get-the-client-ip-address-in-php - this question has some good answers on obtaining the clients IP